# Running pine script in trading view only one time

Tags: pine-script

I've seen this question posted a few times before, but have not seen a clear answer. I would like to run a pine script study only one time, i.e. in connection with the latest bar at the time I add the script to the chart. I do not want the script to then continue running as new bars come in. Is it possible to do this? Effectively, I'd like my script to draw one line, and then keep it there unchanged as new bars come on to the chart.

Comment: Could you be so glad and provide feedback to the answers? That's how Stackoverflow lives

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop the script running per se, but create conditions that only run once on the first real time bar, and then do nothing on subsequent bars.

You can use `barstate.islast` and a var declared boolean variable to store when you've set the line.

```
var plotted = false

var l1 = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = color.red)

drawCondition = barstate.islast and plotted == false

if drawCondition
    line.set_xy1(l1, x = bar_index, y = open)
    line.set_xy2(l1, x = bar_index + 50, y = open)
    plotted := true
```

On historical bars `drawCondition` will be false and the line won't be drawn because `barstate.islast` will return false. On the first bar that `barstate.islast` is true (ie the current real time bar when you add the script), `plotted` will still be false and so the condition will be met, the line will be drawn and `plotted` set to `true`. On any subsequent bars, `plotted` will still be `true` so the condition to draw the line (`drawCondition == false`) won't be met even though `barstate.islast` will be `true`, and so the line won't be modified/redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

According to the previous answer from rumpy, the approach with the semaphore doesn't work in combination with the `barstate.islast`. It took me also some time to figure this out in my scripts.

As soon as an update on the last bar occurs, the state of the script is resetted to the second last bar, so the vsariable plotted is also reset to false. This behavior is described in this article.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html

The variable `barstate.isconfirmed` must also be incorporated. This way you can unsure that the code is only executed on the last bar and only when it closes. On the next last bar (yeah, that sound's weird), your variable plotted is then actually set. The downside is that the code is only executed when the bar closes, so you have to wait and in case the market is closed it "never" happens.

In many circumstances a more appropriate solution is to use the variable `barstate.barstate.islastconfirmedhistory`, which return true on the end of the last historic bar, and also true when the market is closed.

Here is your updated code

```
var plotted = false

var l1 = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = color.red)

drawCondition = barstate.islastconfirmedhistory and plotted == false

if drawCondition
    line.set_xy1(l1, x = bar_index, y = open)
    line.set_xy2(l1, x = bar_index + 50, y = open)
    plotted := true
```

Here is a simple script to observe both behaviors

```
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    log.info("barstate.islastconfirmedhistory: " + str.tostring(bar_index))

var logged = false
if barstate.islast and barstate.isconfirmed
    if not logged
        log.info("barstate.islast and barstate.isconfirmed: " + str.tostring(bar_index))
        logged := true
```